# SQL Server Index column order performance optimization for order by

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing

I have this query:

```
select top 500 * from clicks 
where domainid = 'AC8BBCA4-1CC4-456E-9A85-E7A5C0D7E981' 
order by clickedOn
```

I wonder which index will perform better?

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_p2p] ON [dbo].[clicks]
(
    [domainId],
    [clickedOn] ASC
)
```

Or This?

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_p2p] ON [dbo].[clicks]
(
    [clickedOn] ASC,
    [domainId]
)
```

Comment: I would suggest to review query execution plan. It should give you clues what's better. It is also good to generate e.g. 1M of records into the table and see the difference.

Comment: I'd guess the first one. But you can just check the plans for both and see for yourself.

Comment: @mybrave I am interested in the theoretical aspect of the question.

Comment: Theoretically, index 2 won't be used at all. Because for the kind of indexing it provides, scanning the entire primary key is no slower, and because you `select *`, it's even faster due to no lookups.

Comment: @GSerg is right. You have `SELECT *` but don't `INCLUDE` any other columns in your `NONCLUSTERED INDEX`; so it likely won't be a covering index.

Comment: At first you do filtering - index can help you to get quickly the records with same domainID. Then there is sorting. So first looks better.

Comment: "I am interested in the theoretical aspect of the question" then examine the query plans from both queries with a realistic size and distribution of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first index is clearly better than the second one for this query.

In the first case it can seek into the exact `domainid` and then read the first 500 rows, which are already in `clickedOn` order, and then stop (plus 500 lookups to get the other column values if the table has more than the two columns shown).

The second index might be useful for the query but only in very limited circumstances. It avoids the need to sort by `clickedOn` but does require scanning the index in order and stopping after the first 500 rows matching the `domainId` are found. If you are very lucky then the first 500 rows in `clickedOn` order also match the `domainId` predicate so it too only has to read 500 rows. But chances are this won't be the case. In the worst case there aren't even 500 matching rows to be found and it needs to read the whole index. It too needs to do the 500 lookups to get the other column values.

If the table is relatively small then neither index may be used as SQL Server may decide scanning a covering index and sorting is cheaper than the 500 lookups.

Comment: `scanning a covering index and sorting is cheaper than the 500 lookups` Is that really what you meant to say? You seem to mean that there might be a case where a full table scan can be cheaper than using any of the 2 indexes. Using an index means scanning the index and optionally (table) lookups. But in that phrasing you seem to compare operations that make up using an index, not different cases (using index #1, using index #2, table scan).